# How to add a legend and change transparency in R

Tags: r, plot, legend, transparency, transparent

I have this code that works nicely, as the element is represented by a shape. I need to add a legend for this z value. Perhaps something that reads "Elevation = size of square".

Also, there is another issue I have. By the code that I am using to adjust the shape to show the z element, I cannot figure how to make the points transparent. I have looked at stack overflow and tried a few suggested methods. Yet, I believe it is the way I have written this code that has made this more complicated.

This is my code:

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


inputBrooklyn <- read_xlsx("PlotsManhattan.xlsx")
PercentBK     <- inputBrooklyn$Percent
ComNormBK     <- inputBrooklyn$ComNorm
ElevationBK   <- inputBrooklyn$Elevation


dfx = data.frame(PercentBK, ComNormBK, ElevationBK)

with(dfx, symbols(PercentBK, ComNormBK, squares=ElevationBK, inches=1/3,
                  ann=F, bg= "blue", fg=NULL))
title(xlab = "Slope", ylab = "Normalized Total Complaints")
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not provide us with your data,  we cannot actually run your code. However, this will be pretty close. Try

```
with(dfx, symbols(PercentBK, ComNormBK, squares=ElevationBK, inches=1/3,
                  ann=F, bg= "#0000FF55", fg=NULL))
title(xlab = "Slope", ylab = "Normalized Total Complaints")
text(4, 0.008, "Elevation = size of square")
```

I think the `text` part is self-explanatory. I changed the `bg` color to "#0000FF55" which means Red=0, Green=0, Blue=255, Opacity=85.  Make the number lower for more transparency.

Comment: Amazing. Perfect. Thank you.